# How to make XGBoost work with reg:squaredlogerror?

Tags: python, xgboost

I try to train XGBoost model with `'reg:squaredlogerror'` as an objective, but it always outputs constant. A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

xgb1 = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 60, objective='reg:squaredlogerror')
xgb1.fit(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]), np.array([1, 2, 3]))
xgb1.predict(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]))
```

output:

```
array([1.8770156, 1.8770156, 1.8770156], dtype=float32)
```

Same thing happens on larger sets of data. How do i create an XGBoost model that minimizes squared log error and is not a constant?

Comment: I have just encountered this same issue. As a workaround I am wrapping `XGBRegressor` in `TransformedTargetRegressor` and log-transforming the target variable with objective `reg:squarederror`. I believe they are equivalent. But I would like to know why I can't use `reg:squaredlogerror` directly